# Phusion Passenger doesn't compile in MacOS 10.13 High Sierra (Missing Apache Development Headers)

Tags: macos, passenger, phusion

I've been trying to install Phusion Passenger under macOS X 10.13 High Sierra and the method I usually use is failing because the Apache Development headers seem to be missing. I also tried using Homebrew to install Phusion Passenger and it appears to me that it's failing for the same reason.

I've installed both Xcode 9 and the Command Line Developer tools (which is generally the solution to this problem in previous versions of OS X) but it's not solving it now. Does anyone have any insight into this issue and/or any suggestions as to how I might fix this?

Comment: for me `brew upgrade passenger` failed with error message `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/apache2/ap_hooks.h:39:10: fatal error: 'apr.h' file not found`

Answer (score 0):

This is something that the folks at Phusion are addressing in the next release. There were quite a few difficult changes in the High Sierra dev environment that need to be addressed.

There’s a chance that the Sierra bottle from home brew might work. Otherwise just wait for the next release.

Comment: I did try the Homebrew installation. Unfortunately, that didn't work either. As I mentioned in my original post, that appeared to fail for the same reason. Any idea what a timeframe might look like on that? Not super familiar with Phusion's schedule on things like that...

Comment: Did you pass the `--force-bottle` flag? Since there's no HS bottle you'll need that to force the Sierra bottle to install.

Comment: I tried `brew upgrade --force-bottle passenger` but when running apache it crashed.

Comment: 5.1.12 complies but now I'm having this issue...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48254851/phusion-passenger-5-1-12-osx-10-13-server-5-4